# android : all of alarm were cleared how to get them back

Tags: android, alarmmanager

*first of all , i would like to apologize for my English its bad*

**all of alarm that i create by this class**

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(SETALARM.this, ALARMRECEIVER.class);
    intent.putExtra("pk", pk);
    sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, pk, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE); 
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),60000, sender);
```

**were cleared when device is shut off**

**what should i do to restore all of alarm back**

thank you very much for your help

**edit**

**here is receiver class**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {         
    WakeLocker.acquire(context);   


    pk = Integer.parseInt(intent.getExtras().get("pk").toString());     
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(context,ALERT.class);
    intent2.putExtra("pk", pk);
    intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent2); 

    WakeLocker.release();
}}
```

Comment: By 'asleep' do you mean 'shut off'?  If the device is 'asleep' the alarms should persist.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you lose the alarms when the device is turned off then this issue has been addressed well here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5439320/374866

Comment: You can fire off your alarms in the BroadcastReceiver if you want

Comment: please check my question again

Comment: You cannot start an Activity in the BroadcastReceiver onReceive when the phone is booting.  You can start a Service that will start your alarms.  See more about that here -->  http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/LocalService.html